# Ionic 6 modal controller pops up disabled with opaque shield

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my Ionic 6.20.1 + Angular 15.2.7 app, I am calling a popup modal from a service.
**The modal pops up but all its controls are not responding** and there is an opaque "shield" covering it. See picture:

[image]

It is displayed as a picture - no response to any tapping. Only when tapping outside of the modal - it dissapears.

**Why is it behaving like this?**

The service calling the modal:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { EmailService } from './email.service';
import { GeneralServices } from './general-service';
import { UserInputComponent } from '../components/user-input/user-input.component';
import { BehaviorSubject, map } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailVerificationService {

  private emailSender;
  userInput$ = new BehaviorSubject('');

  constructor(private email: EmailService, private general: GeneralServices, public modalController: ModalController) { }

  verifyEmail(email: string) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const randCode: number = this.general.randNumber(5);
      console.log('Random verification code received: ', randCode);

      this.emailSender = this.email.sendEmail(email, 'Please verify your email for Simplify', 'Your verification code is: ' + randCode.toString()).subscribe(async (emailResult: {resultCode:number, resultMessage:string}) => {
        console.log('Returned from email seding test: ', emailResult);
        console.log('Returned from email seding test resultCode: ', emailResult.resultCode);
        if (emailResult.resultCode == 250) {          
          this.openIonModal();
          this.userInput$.pipe(
            map((userInput) => {
              if (Number(userInput) == randCode) {
                console.log('Resolved email verification with code : ' + userInput);
                resolve(true);
              } else {
                console.log('Failed email verification with code : ' + userInput);
                resolve(false);
              }
            })
          );          
        } else {
          console.log('Error returned from sendEmail service in email-verification service');
          reject('Error sending email');
        }
      });

      
    });

    return promise;
  }

  async openIonModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: UserInputComponent,
      cssClass: 'user-input-modal-css',
      componentProps: {
        'modalTitle': "Email Verification",
        'modalQuestion': "We have sent a 5-digit verification code to your email. Please type the code below:"
      }
    });
    modal.onDidDismiss().then((modalData: any) => {
      console.log('Received user email verification code : ' + modalData);
      if (modalData !== null) {        
        this.userInput$.next(modalData);
        //this.userCode = Number(modalData);        
      }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }


  ngOnDestry() {
    if (this.emailSender) {
      this.emailSender.unsubscribe();
      this.userInput$.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

The modal template:

```
<ion-content id="modal-wrapper">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col id="modal-title-col">
        {{ modalTitle }}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="3" text-center id="modal-icon-col">
        <ion-icon name="help-circle" size="large" color="primary"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>      
      <ion-col>
        <div class="input-wrapper">          
          <ion-label>{{ modalQuestion }}</ion-label>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div id="modal-user-input">
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="userInput" type="number" inputmode="numeric" clearInput placeholder="00000" label="" fill="outline"></ion-input>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    <ion-row>  
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col id="modal-buttons-col">
        <ion-button (click)="submitModal()" color="primary">Submit</ion-button>
        <ion-button (click)="cancelModal()" color="medium">Cancel</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

The modal controller:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-input',
  templateUrl: './user-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-input.component.scss'],
})
export class UserInputComponent {

  @Input() modalTitle: string;
  @Input() modalQuestion: string;

  userInput: number | null;
  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) { }

  async submitModal() {
    if (this.userInput) {
      await this.modalController.dismiss(this.userInput);
    }    
  }


  async cancelModal() {    
    await this.modalController.dismiss(0);        
  }

}
```

Modal styling:

```
.input-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#modal-wrapper {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
#modal-title-col {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 160%;
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
    color:antiquewhite;
}

#modal-icon-col {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

#modal-buttons-col {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#modal-user-input {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 250%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

I have this in global.scss:

```
.user-input-modal-css {
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 10%;
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```